# Basic Address Formatting

Tags: format, street-address

I have hundreds of addresses that need to be formatted.

The formation looks like this currently-

7000 91ST ST E PALMETTO, FL 99999

I would like it to look like this-

7000 91ST ST E

PALMETTO, FL 99999

I have looked around and if there was a code that would allow me to find a word before the comma and put all of that onto a newline it would make it a lot easier. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours.

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried learning multiple things, from Excel VBA, that is where the addresses reside, in an Excel document. I am currently trying to use some sort of regex.

Comment: I'm not sure how to provide you a regex string, because I can't figure one out that works.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me what I use, I'm just asking the community for ideas/solutions

Answer (score 1):

If these are supposed to be real addresses, use proper address validation software, such as that provided by [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com). Try the online list processing tool that will allow you to submit csv address data and in a few seconds, provide an output file with all the addresses validated and formatted:

https://smartystreets.com/products/list

If you'd like direct access to the underlying validation tools, there's an API for that:

https://smartystreets.com/products/apis/us-street-api

Depending on what languages you use, there's probably an SDK to simplify scripting access to the above API:

https://smartystreets.com/docs/sdk

Unfortunately, the address you provided above [isn't actually a real/valid address](https://smartystreets.com/products/apis/us-street-api?auth-id=21102174564513388&candidates=10&street=7000%2091ST%20ST%20E&city=palmetto&state=fl&zipcode=99999&match=invalid&method=GET) (even after discarding the bogus `99999` ZIP Code).

---

Full disclosure: I'm a software developer at SmartyStreets and helped develop the services mentioned above.